# What is $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\| I+At\|-1}{t}$? Is it the spectral abscissa?

Tags: matrices, reference-request, normed-spaces

I vaguely remember this, and after a lot of googling, I couldn't find anything about it. So I appreciate if someone provides a reference or explains what is this and where it is used. I saw in a book that for a square matrix $A$, there is some kind of measure defined as:
$$\mu(A)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\| I+At\|-1}{t}$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix and $\|.\|$ (possibly) denotes the euclidean norm. I didn't find any name/reference/usefulness for this kind of measure.

**Edit.** I changed the title for future references. The wikipedia article for [spectral abscissa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_abscissa) looks too short and incomplete. And there is no mention of that on [wolfram mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/search/?query=spectral+abscissa&x=0&y=0) either. Although it looks like a useful thing, especially in the [stability analysis](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/123456789/159081/2/siopt_revised.pdf) of system matrices.

Comment: Looks like spectral abscissa

Comment: @ValerySaharov the spectral abscissa has a different definition. Do you have any proof that its definition is equivalent to this one?

Comment: It's no surprise that this definition is not mentioned anywhere. Why should anyone use this one instead of $\Re\lambda$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(B,||*||)$ is a complex unital Banach algebra (the unit is denoted by $e$) und $B'$ is the topological dual of $B$ , then let

$D:=\{f \in B':||f||=1=f(e)\}$.

For $a \in A$ let $V(a)$ be defined by

$$V(a)=\{f(a): f \in D\}.$$

$V(a)$ is called the numerical range of $a$.

It holds that

$$ \lim_{t\to 0+}\frac{\| I+at\|-1}{t}= \sup \{Re \lambda: \lambda \in V(a)\}$$.

A good reference is:

Bonsall/Duncan: Complete Normed Algebras.

Comment: Thanks, but I read about that when I didn't know anything about Banach algebras. I mean, it was all about matrices.

Comment: Let $n \in \mathbb N$ and $B$ the algebra of all complex $n \times n$ - matrices. If $||*||$ is a norm on $B$ such that $||ab|| \le ||a||*||b||$ for all $a,b \in B$, then $B$ is a Banach algebra .

Comment: So for a matrix, as Valery said, it is equivalent to the spectral abscissa?

Comment: Yes, but a liitle bit effort is needed to proof this.